# Which tool you use to mount a floppy usb with a tiling wm

Tags: mount, desktop-environment

I use a tiling wm without an desktop environment. So no notification when I plug in a usb stick for example. At the moment personally I use the mount and umount command line, but maybe you have most interesting usage. Do you use a file manager like pcmanfm or nautilus, but that trouble me to use it only for that. Or maybe you have a tool which automatically mounts the media when it is plugged.

How do you usually manage this case.

Comment: without graphical environment with `mount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to z3bra for having pointed me ldm project some was a very useful project:

https://github.com/LemonBoy/ldm

It's a lightweight device mounter following the UNIX philosophy written in C and based on udev and libmount. It works really well.

To install on debian from the source:

```
git clone https://github.com/LemonBoy/ldm.git
make
sudo make install
```

And the to use like a daemon use -d option:

```
export USERID=`id -u`
export GROUPID=`id -g`
sudo ldm -d -u $USERID -g $GROUPID
```

It's perfect and now when you plug a usb it is automatically mount.